# Loading many images simultaneously causes Activity/Fragment to lag

Tags: image, performance, android-studio, android-glide, android-tv

I'm new to developping **android TV applications**. I am building a *quizz game* which needs a lot of **images, videos, mp3 and gifs** to show up simultaneously at a given time depending on the business logic of the game. I am using:

- glide to show images / gifs (images are High Definition);
- android Async and Handler / Thread / Runnable pattern to play sounds;
- android video player to play videos (videos are High Definition);
- nested RelativeLayout / LinearLayout to display the views;
- `View.setVisibility(GONE)` to hide views and `View.setVisibility(VISIBLE)` to show it.

**My problem is this:**

On a Samsung galaxy tab 4 device, the game is smooth! But on a TV device, **TCL 1920x1080 40dpi** that should run the game, it is laggy.

I have read a lot of blog posts about how to optimize code ; like using ConstraintLayout instead of nested layouts, using `View.setVisibility(INVISIBLE)` instead of `View.setVisibility(GONE)` and I am also planning to use Picasso instead of Glide to get some fps but I'm not confident about all those. Can anyone give me advices on how to optimise my code to get some more fps (I mean getting like 10 or 15 fps not just 2 or 3)? Thanks in advance guys, cheer up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in android manifest I added:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

solved the problem got **15fps** higher.